# Taskbar hides jFrame on startup?

Tags: java, swing

When my projects starts the lower part of the main Jframe goes beneath the taskbar.

[image]

how to solve this problem.

Comment: It's a normal thing, every window goes under the taskbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use frame.setSize(...);

Instead use:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Or if you do manually need to set the size then use:

```
Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
```

and then make sure you subtract out the insets.top and inserts.bottom from the height of the screen. Then the size of your frame must be less then that value.

Comment: when i use frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
it covers the whole screen.
but i want it to be of size 780x750.

Comment: I clarified my answer.